# What is a related SE site for this question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I could not find a related Stack Exchange site to bring up the following question. Please let me know the related SE site.

**Question:**

> What is the best paraphrasing application.

Answer (score 4):

I can't guarantee an answer but - if you mean software - and you need to include a platform and what you need and so on, [software recommendations would be the site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). This goes into [detail](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and here's a [shorter version](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/information-that-every-question-needs-to-include) of their recommended information you need to include when asking a question. .

*Great* paraphrasing does involve some personal style, and understanding so I doubt its doable in software, but if there's any site to ask, it would be software recommendations.